# Change storyboard UIImageView to own class with backgroundcolor

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift

I want to draw the background image on my own, so I decided to implement a UIImageView class and connect it in the Storyboard.
As first task I just want to set the backgroundcolor of the image on my own, but it's never shown. Image just stays blank.

That's the class:

```
class FirstBackgroundImage : UIImageView {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

}

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

override required init(image: UIImage!) {
    super.init(image: image)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

}
```

That's how i connected it:

[image: uiimageview class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested with

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIImageView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Works as expected. You must have some other error - maybe placement and sizing of the view due to Autolayout? A good way to test is to set the color in IB and check if you can see it.

Comment: yes, it was autolayout. i deleted all the constraints and made them new ;). thx